# Storing session variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, session

I'm trying to store some dictionary values into a session variable using JS but is not working well. It is storing undefined values and when this function it's used without storing it as session is not giving those values.

```
sessionStorage.color_array = generateColorsForKidList();
if (!sessionStorage.color_array) {
 sessionStorage.color_array = generateColorsForKidList();
}

function generateColorsForKidList() {
//code
color_array.push({
  color: getRandomColor(),
  kid: kid,
});
return color_array;
}

function fillExamKiddata(exams, currentMonth, currentYear) {
//code
var color_array = sessionStorage.color_array;
var exams = $('.exam_event');
exams.each(function(index) {
 for (var k = 0; k < color_array.length; k++) {
  if ($(this).find('small').eq(3).text().trim() == color_array[k]['kid'].trim()) {
//giving index error
}
```

Error:

[image]

I have used the functions sessionStorage.getItem() and sessionStorage.setItem() but the result is the same.
Any idea if I'm using in a wrong way the session values?

Thanks for reading!

Edit: Content of generateColorsForKidList()
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage.color_array = generateColorsForKidList();` change to

`sessionStorage.color_array = JSON.stringify(generateColorsForKidList());`

Stringify the values while saving.

`var color_array = sessionStorage.color_array;` change to

`var color_array = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.color_array);`

Parse the values before using.

Sample code

```
const colors = [
  { color: "#a", kid: "abc" },
  { color: "#b", kid: "xyz" }
];

const setSS = (arr, name) =>
  window.sessionStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(arr));
const getSS = name => JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(name));

console.log(colors);
setSS(colors, "my_colors");
const color_array = getSS("my_colors");

for (var k = 0; k < color_array.length; k++) {
  console.log(color_array[k]["kid"].trim());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but the result is the same. @Siva Kondapi Venkata

Comment: @adriano009, Can you provide the contents of `console.log(generateColorsForKidList())`?

Comment: @adriano009, Can you try sample code  (I just updated based on data in answer) in your chrome browser console?